# Applescript: Open Excel File and Save in a Different Format (same name and path)

Tags: excel, macos, applescript

I have a folder of .xls files of which some are genuine excel files and some are excel xml files (but still with the .xls extension). To work with the files in a separate program, I'm trying to convert them all to a consistent format (Excel 98-2004) and want to use an applescript to do this while retaining the original file names and directory structure.

As of now, I have a working loop and list of files, and am accomplishing everything but the save function:

```
set file_Name to "/Users/me/path/to/data.xls"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file_Name
    save workbook as workbook (active workbook) filename file_Name file format (Excel98to2004 file format) with overwrite
    close workbooks
    quit
end tell
```

When I run this code, I get the following replies:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open "/Users/drewmcdonald/Desktop/Madhupur_10February2014.xls"
    get active workbook
        --> active workbook
    save workbook as workbook (active workbook) filename "/Users/drewmcdonald/Desktop/test.xlsx"
        --> missing value
    close every workbook
    quit
end tell
```

The spreadsheets are successfully opening and closing, but the file format is not changing and I don't know what to make of the "missing value" error. Any idea how to get this to work? Thanks!

EDIT: Just noticed that the file format parameter is missing from the reply text, so I'm guessing the problem is in there.

Comment: did you get this worked out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I needed to `set` a workbook name variable to `get full name of active workbook` before trying to save it. This is because the workbook name that Excel assigns as it opens sheets is somewhat inconsistent. Final code looks like this:

```
set file_Name to "/Users/me/path/to/data.xls"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file_Name
    set wkbk_name to get full name of active workbook
    save workbook as workbook wkbk_name filename file_Name file format Excel98to2004 file format with overwrite
    close workbooks
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: only works for 2011, not later version of excel.   see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/applescript-support-in-excel-2016/1015a855-3696-402e-b833-9cc4e83cf741

Comment: Thanks for following up Jerry