# Applescript to open spreadsheet, make changes, & save

Tags: macos, applescript

I have just begun using Applescript & have the following question: how to use applescript on OSX El Capitan to open a spreadsheet, make changes/additions/deletions, then save & replace file.  Did not see anything on Stackoverflow that would answer my question. Thanks so much.

Comment: When you say Spreadsheet, what application are you using? The power of AppleScript comes from manipulating other applications, but not all applications are created equal.

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345166/applescript-open-excel-file-and-save-in-a-different-format-same-name-and-path  It may not answer your question fully, but see if it helps, and if so past answer.

Comment: I am using Open Office & output files as either ods or xls format..